# Creating nested folder in Sharepoint with Graph API fails

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I can create a nested folder `/folder1/folder2` in (personal) OneDrive with the following Graph request (using the beta API):

```
POST drives/{id}/root:/folder1:/children

{
  "name": "folder2",
  "folder": {},
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
}
```

Here, `folder1` didn't exist beforehand; the one API call creates both it and `folder1/folder2`.

However, the same code fails for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business with a 404 error. Is this type of request supported? I'd rather not have to make a separate API call for every level of nesting.

I'm asking this because I'm not sure whether my site has policies that cause the request to fail, or because the API actually doesn't support it.

Comment: AFAIK, you should give the folder name(while giving path) or folder id(while giving id) of the parent folder to create a sub folder inside it, because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) should have the `parent-item-id` to create a folder. The only way is it make a separate API call for every level as you said. You can get the path property in the response when you create a folder, you can use it to automate calls easily.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma the code above works for personal OneDrive; I've verified this

Comment: This is despite the docs not mentioning it

Comment: Yeah, I have also tested it in personal which worked but not with work account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Remove `name` parameter from the body and use `PATCH` instead of `POST`. Specify the path in the URL.

```
PATCH drives/{id}/root:/folder1/folder2

{
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
}
```

Tested using `v1.0` and `beta` for OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Oh sweet, didn't know you could use PATCH to create a new file/folder.